# Передать данные значений Json в список

Tags: python, json

Как можно передать значения из Json в обычный одномерный список?

```
json = [{"res": 5}, {"res": 8}, {"res": 11}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
json = [{"res": 5}, {"res": 8}, {"res": 11}]
lst = list(map(lambda x: x["res"], json))
```